# Forge offline Viewer creating new symbols

Tags: autodesk-forge

In the forge offline viewer, is it possible to draw some lines for creating new  symbols in the drawing and get the coordinates of the symbol? Is it possible to create hatch patterns in the drawing in offline mode? Is it possible to get  handles of all objects in a particular layer?

Comment: Maybe check out this blog, it uses custom measure tool to draw area plan: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/area-planning-tool-forge-viewer-and-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Forge Viewer is for viewing only purpose, there is no formal creation API available currently, and the loaded model is read only. Through the viewer is built on the top of three.js r71. but it's a private owned maintained one, it doesn't support all features of the three.js.

However, there are a way to add custom shapes onto the Viewer viewport via the [markup extension](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/using-autodeskviewingmarkupscore-extension). Markup ext is archive via the drawing [svg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) graphic to the markup canvas. It will make your life easier to add custom graphics. This code snippet is showing how to enter markup editing mode.

```
var markup;
viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore').then(function(markupsExt){
  markup = markupsExt;
});

markup.enterEditMode();
var cloud = new Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.EditModeCloud(markup)
markup.changeEditMode(cloud);
```

References:

- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/using-autodeskviewingmarkupscore-extension
- https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v5/reference/javascript/markupscore